# Error in datetime not match in Jupyter Notebbok

Tags: python, project

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    455             try:
--> 456                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    457                 dta = DatetimeArray(values, dtype=tz_to_dtype(tz))

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-97fe3fa310aa> in <module>
----> 1 Uber_2014['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Uber_2014['Date/Time'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    803             result = arg.map(cache_array)
    804         else:
--> 805             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
    806             result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    807     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    458                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(dta, name=name)
    459             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 460                 raise e
    461 
    462     if result is None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    421             if result is None:
    422                 try:
--> 423                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
    424                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
    425                     )

pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data '09-01-2014 00:01' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

Comment: Post your sample code as well as expected output

Comment: The error is pretty easy to understand, you try to convert string values to datetime with format  `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"` but your data is `'09-01-2014 00:01'` so that doesnt match, what do you want ?

Comment: For what the parameter `format` expects, the `pandas` documentation for the function `to_datetime()` at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html refers to the Python documentation for the underlying implementation at  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior and in general when you call a library function, and it doesn't do what you expect, the first thing to try is *consult the documentation*.

Comment: Uber_2014['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Uber_2014['Date/Time'], format="%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")